# Android 11 file sharing bug when I use hupu app

Tags: android, file-sharing, android-11, miui

[Bug when I use Hupu app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfj9i.jpg)

I updated my MIUI version to 12.2.1.0 last night. When I was using hupu app this morning, I was told that 'Sharing exceptions, Android 11 and above require a file provider for sharing.'So anyone knows how to share files in Android 11？
Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Well in the same way as in versions below 11. ACTION_SEND. The FileProvider is already needed since 7/N.

Comment: But... This does not look like a programming question.